# Pairing different gam smoothing regression (mgcv) to ggally [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, mgcv, ggally

I struggled with this code to pair different gam' smoothing regression (bs="cs" and bs="tp") using GGally:

```
sel1<-select(rekap,c('Total_Ni', 'Total_Mg', 'Total_Fe', 'CEC', 'pH','SWC'))## selecting column

str(sel1)
tibble [36 x 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Total_Ni: num [1:36] 1750 1565 1249 853 959 ...
 $ Total_Mg: num [1:36] 1468 1558 1164 813 915 ...
 $ Total_Fe: num [1:36] 381 300 172 173 144 ...
 $ CEC     : num [1:36] 105 132 117 118 141 ...
 $ pH      : num [1:36] 4.21 4.22 4.49 4.43 4.05 4.09 5.21 5.27 4.32 4.29 ...
 $ SWC     : num [1:36] 435 511 497 517 621 ...

    
my_fn3 <- function(data, mapping, method="gam", ...){
      p3 <- ggplot(data = sel1, mapping = mapping) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method=method,colour="blue", ...)
      p3
    }   

gamformula<- y ~ s(x,bs="tp")

my_fn4 <- function(data, mapping, method=mgcv::gam(), ...){
      p4 <- ggplot(data = sel1, mapping = mapping) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method="gam", formula=gamformula, colour="orangered2", ...)
      p4
    }   

plot2 <- ggpairs(sel1, columnLabels = c("Total Ni", "Total Mg", "Total Fe", "CEC", "pH","SWC"),
            upper=list(continuous =my_fn3),
            lower=list(continuous =my_fn4))+ 
            theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x=(element_text(size=rel(0.7), angle=0)),
            axis.text.y=(element_text(size=rel(0.7), angle=0)), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA,colour = "grey35"))
```

I noticed the differences of the lines and CI, so i thought maybe it works. I can run mgcv::gam() in separated sesion (just to model the dataset and verify the smoothers), but i had no idea when the formula is linking with GGally. So, i am not very confident with the graph.

Does anyone have the idea about my code wrong or not?

[image: This is the Plot]